# Runtime error not showing when using asyncio to run discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm developing discord bot with discord.py==2.1.0.

I use cog to write the main function that I wanna use, but I found when the whole bot is wrapped in  async function and called by `asyncio.run()`, my terminal won't show any error message when there is any runtime error in my cog script.

Here is the example application. I stored my bot token in environment variable.

- bot.py

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

token = os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.members = True
        intents.message_content = True
        
        description = "bot example."

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), 
            intents=intents,
            description=description
        )

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')

bot = Bot()

async def load_extensions():
    for f in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if f.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

- ./cogs/my_cog.py

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ready")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def command(self, ctx):
        test_error_message()   # An runtime error example
        print("Command")

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

- Command that I run in terminal to start the bot.

```
python bot.py
```

- When I type `!command` in the discord channel, there is no error message showing in the terminal, but there is no "Command" printed out so I'm sure the code stopped at the line I called `test_error_message()`
- I expected that it should show error message normally, but I cannot find useful reference to make it work :(
- There is one reason I need to use asyncio, I have a task loop to run in the bot, like the code below.

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def avatar_update():
    # code here

async def main():
    async with bot:
        avatar_update.start()
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(token)
```

- I would happy to know if there are some great practice to handle error in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Client.start()` doesn't configure logging, so if you want to use that then you have to do it yourself (there's `setup_logging` to add a basic config). `run()` configures logging for you.

For more info, read the docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html?highlight=logging

Comment: I followed the doc about logging, added a line `discord.utils.setup_logging()` solved the problem!! By the way I run `bot.run()` in an asyncio event loop, I got runtime error because `asyncio.run(runner())` is called, so I choose the other way to go. Thank you for the reply so quickly!

Comment: Yes run() already calls that so you can't. If you use run () and want to do some async setup, you can use setup_hook.